# Numpy: Select row multiple times using different indices array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following array.

```
l = np.asarray([1,3,5,7])

Out[552]: array([1, 3, 5, 7])
```

I can select the row twice using a index array `np.asarray([[0,1],[1,2]])`:

```
l[np.asarray([[0,1],[1,2]])]
Out[553]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [3, 5]])
```

It doesn't work if the index array have different length on each row:

```
l[np.asarray([[1,3],[1,2,3]])]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-555-3ec2ab141cd4>", line 1, in <module>
    l[np.asarray([[1,3],[1,2,3]])]
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

My desired output for this example would be:

```
array([[3, 7],
       [3, 5, 7]])
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: numpy doesn't support ragged (non-rectangular arrays), so you might want to think of other datastructures you could use to store your output (like lists).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the closest I can get.

```
import numpy as np
l = np.asarray([1, 3, 5, 7])
idx = [[1,3],[1,2,3]]
output = np.array([np.array(l[i]) for i in idx])
print output
```

Result:

```
[array([3, 7]) array([3, 5, 7])]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is closer. Maybe it can't get any better if Numpy doesn't support ragged array as @DSM mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, I think `list` is better for such indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you are after if you build the lists seperately.

**Code:**

```
l = np.asarray([1, 3, 5, 7])

# Build a sample array
print(np.array([[3, 7], [3, 5, 7]]))   

# do the lookups into the original array 
print(np.array([list(l[[1, 3]]), list(l[[1, 2, 3]])]))
```

**Results:**

```
[[3, 7] [3, 5, 7]]
[[3, 7] [3, 5, 7]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my index array has many rows and this method won't scale.

Comment: @Allen, Often a good idea to put these sorts of details into the question, and not left as happy surprises later.